# How to add a file jquery on view razor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, view

I have this view and this works fine

as you see I have added a section (required:false) on _layout 
and until now there is not problem,

```
@model final2.Models.ObjetosUnidos.HelperVenta
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";

}

@*
    <>
*@


@section JavaScript
{

 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(
        function () {

            var $loading = $('#cargando').hide();
            $(document)
            .ajaxStart(function () {

                $loading.show();
            })
            .ajaxStop(function () {
                $loading.hide();
            })



            $("#btnselectcliente").click(
                function () {

                    $("#diviniciarventa").hide();

                    $.when(
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "post",
                            dataType: "html",
                            url: '@Url.Action("mostrarcuerpo", "venta")',
                            data: { idcliente: $("#selectcliente").val() }

                        })
                         ).then(
                         function (data) {


                             $("#divcuerpo").html(data);

                         }, function (error) { alert(error.responseText); }
                         );
                }

                         );


            $(this).on("click", "#btnbuscar", function (e) {
                /// Do some stuff ...


                var idventa1 = $("#idventa").val();



                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: "html",
                    url: '@Url.Action("buscarproducto", "venta")',
                    data: { texto: $("#txtbuscar").val(), idventa: idventa1 },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#divtableproductos").html(data);
                    },
                    error: function (error) { alert(error.error); }
                });

            });



            var productoid = 0;
            var cantidad = 0.0;
            var precio = 0.0;
            var iva = 0.0;
            var nombre = "";
            var codigo = "";
            var ventaid = "";
            var cantidadelegida = 0.0;
            $(this).on(
            {
                click: function () {

                    productoid = parseInt(this.cells["productoid"].textContent);
                    cantidad = parseFloat(this.cells["cantidad"].textContent);
                    precio = parseFloat(this.cells["precio"].textContent);
                    iva = parseFloat(this.cells["iva"].textContent);
                    nombre = (this.cells["nombre"].textContent);
                    codigo = (this.cells["codigo"].textContent);
                    ventaid = $("#idventa").val();

                    $("#txtnombre").val(nombre);
                    $("#txtcodigo").val(codigo);

                }
            }, "#tableproductos tbody tr");



            var colordefault = "";
            $(this).on({
                mouseenter: function () {
                    //stuff to do on mouse enter
                    colordefault = $(this).css("background-color");
                    $(this).css("background-color", "#ff0");
                },
                mouseleave: function () {
                    $(this).css("background-color", colordefault);
                }
            }, "#tableproductos tbody tr");

            $(this).on(
            {

                click: function () {
                    cantidadelegida = $("#txtcantidad").val();
                    if (cantidadelegida < 0 || cantidadelegida > cantidad) {
                        alert("Cantidad debe estar entre 0 y " + cantidad);
                        return;
                    }
                    texto = $("#txtbuscar").val();
                    actualizaprodydetalle(productoid, cantidadelegida, ventaid, texto);

                }
            }, "#btnagregar");


            function actualizaprodydetalle(_productoid, _cantidadelegida, _ventaid, _texto) {
                $.when(
                $.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: "html",
                    url: '@Url.Action("muestradetalle", "venta")',
                    data: { productoid: _productoid, cantidad: _cantidadelegida, ventaid: _ventaid }
                }),
                $.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: "html",
                    url: '@Url.Action("buscarproducto", "venta")',
                    data: { texto: _texto, idventa: ventaid }
                })

                ).then(
                function (data1, data2) {

                    $("#divdetalle").html(data1);
                    $("#divtableproductos").html(data2);

                }
                );
            }





            iddetalle = 0;
            $(this).on(
            {
                mouseover: function () {

                    iddetalle = parseInt(this.cells["iddetalle"].textContent);


                }
            }, "#tbldetalle tbody tr");


            $(this).on(
            {
                click: function () {


                    texto = $("#txtbuscar").val();


                    try {

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "post",
                            dataType: "html",
                            url: '@Url.Action("actualizadetalle", "venta")',
                            data: {
                                iddetalle: iddetalle,
                                texto: texto
                            },
                            success: function (data) {

                                $("#divmodal").html(data);
                            },
                            error: function (dat) {
                                alert(dat.responseText);
                                alert(dat.statusText);

                            }
                        });
                    }
                    catch (ex) {
                        alert(ex.message);
                    }


                }
            }, "#btnmodificar");



            $(this).on(
            {

                click: function () {



                    var productoid5 = $("#adproductoid").val();
                    var ventaid5 = $("#idventa").val();
                    var texto5 = $("#adtexto").val();

                    if (parseFloat($("#txtnuevacantidad").val()) < 0 || parseFloat($("#txtnuevacantidad").val()) > (parseFloat($("#addisponible").val()) + parseFloat($("#adcantidadactual").val()))) {
                        alert("Cantidad debe estar entre 0 y " + (parseFloat($("#addisponible").val()) + parseFloat($("#adcantidadactual").val())));
                        return;
                    }

                    var cantidad5 = parseFloat($("#txtnuevacantidad").val()) - parseFloat($("#adcantidadactual").val());

                    actualizaprodydetalle(productoid5, cantidad5, ventaid5, texto5);
                    $('#divmodal').html("");

                }
            }, "#btnnuevacantidad");




            $(this).on(
            {
                click: function () {



                    var ventaid5 = $("#idventa").val();

                    try {

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "post",
                            dataType: "html",
                            url: '@Url.Action("finalizarventa", "venta")',
                            data: {
                                ventaid: ventaid5

                            },
                            success: function (data) {

                                $("#divmodal").html(data);
                            },
                            error: function (dat) {
                                alert(dat.responseText);
                                alert(dat.statusText);

                            }
                        });
                    }
                    catch (ex) {
                        alert(ex.message);
                    }


                }
            }, "#btnfinalizarvta");





            cambiofinal = 0;
            $(this).on(
            {
                keypress: function (e) {

                    try {


                        if (e.which == 13) {//Enter key pressed


                            total = parseFloat($(this).val());
                            total = total.toFixed(2);
                            cobrar = parseFloat($("#fvprecio").val());
                            cobrar = cobrar.toFixed(2);
                            cambio = (total - cobrar);
                            cambio = cambio.toFixed(2);
                            cambiofinal = cambio;
                            $("#txtcambio").val(cambio);


                        }

                    }

                    catch (ex) {

                        alert("Solo números flotantos por favór " + ex.message);
                        return false;
                    }

                }
            }, "#txtentrega");

            $(this).on(
            {
                click: function (e) {

                    $('#divmodal').html("");

                }
            }, "#fvcerrar");

            $(this).on(
            {
                click: function (e) {

                    if (cambiofinal < 0) {
                        alert("Dinero Insuficiente");
                        return;
                    }

                    $('#divmodal').html("");

                    var ventaid5 = $("#idventa").val();
                    //ventafinalizada
                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "post",
                        dataType: "text",
                        url: '@Url.Action("ventafinalizada", "venta")',
                        data: { ventaid: ventaid5 },
                        async: false,
                        success: function (response) {
                            alert(response);
                            window.close();
                        },
                        error: function (data) { alert("Ocurrio un errorxx"); }

                    }
                    );




                }
            }, "#fvfinalizarventa");


            //$("#buscar").keypress(function (e) {
            //    if (e.which == 13) {//Enter key pressed
            //        //$("#btnaceptar").click();//Trigger search button click event
            //        alert("buscar enter")
            //        buscar();
            //    }
            //});

        });
</script>



}





 <div id="cargando">
     <img src="~/Images/cargandoajax.gif" />
     </div> ...
```

I know to add the Javascript code in a file is a good practic, 
then  I copy

```
 $(document).ready(
            function () {...}
```

in a file but it does not work

```
@section JavaScript
{


    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/scriptventa.js"></script>

}
```

what am i doing wrong?

I tried doing it too

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/scriptventa.js"></script> (not using @section) but it does not work
```

this is happening when the javascript code is on a file, I believe its caused by this line

```
  url: '@Url.Action("mostrarcuerpo", "venta")',
```

[image]

Comment: If you are putting your js code in a separate `.js` file then do not
 copy `@section Javascript` and what do you mean by _do not work_?

Comment: I update,  i didnt copy @section Javascript but it does not work neigther

Comment: Checked your console for any errors?? Did you refer the file in either layout or in bundles??

Comment: not on bundles,  and on _layout neither, I believe if I added it on _layout then its going to be executed on all views (i dont want that)

Comment: Ok let me explain! You have your file referred in some page and if you see your page flow the `jquery.*.js` [* ->version] file will be referred at the end of layout with some bundles and before that you page will be loaded in `renderBody()` right? along with that you are loading your `js` file which is getting executed first and thus you might get error in console saying `$ is undefined`! So I suggest to put your `jquery` bundle at the top of the `layout` with `css` bundles and then give a try!!

Comment: Ok I believe the error is on this line url: '@Url.Action("mostrarcuerpo", "venta")', which works fine when javascript code is on view but it does not work when it's on javascript file.

Comment: What the error says?

Comment: Is `mostrarcuerpo`a partial view or a view with layout referred?

Comment: I change @Url.Action("mostrarcuerpo", "venta") by /SomeController/SomeAction and this works (and all where I had @url.action) I have read this works only when the JavaScript is on View, this works and if this is on a file.js this does not work, this enters to venta/index again, because @url.action... was not recognized, then passed the image I added